# How best to present publications in different areas on a CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I am trying to list my publications in my curriculum vitae. But, because I have publications in three fields *x, y, z* of study such that *x* is my major and *y, z* are not, I am looking for how to best display them so that it can be emphasized that I have works in different areas.

Comment: In order of publication date is standard.

Comment: Thanks so much. At first I use this style. Later, however, I want to emphasize that I have works in different areas...

Comment: If not given the two following conditions, I simply wouldn't do it: 1. The fields are _truly_ different and not related to each other. 2. You have several publications within each of the three fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just make three lists of publications (one for each field) and place each with its own subheading under the general heading "Publications"?

i.e.:

## Publications

#### Biology

- pub 1
- pub 2

#### Astronomy

- pub 1

#### Mathematics

- pub 1
- pub 2

Comment: If the importance of topics is not important for you, you can also list your topics alphabetically to make it easier for finding a specific topic.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: There are three topics. Alphabetical order isn't going to be that obvious or important. And even then, the primary field should be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [David Ketchesons answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/27863/15723).  One alternative is to keep a standard method such as by year, and create tags at the end.

> My Publication 1, Journal of Biology, 2013 **[Biology]**
>
> My Publication 2, Journal of Mathematics, 2012 **[Mathematics]**

This will make it easy to see your publications and may give faster accessibility to your career.  For example, if you started in field X, and then went to field Y, and now you are at field Z, the chronological order will show tags at earlier publications with field X, and more recent at field Z.  In the same way, if you want to show how you publish in different fields throughout your career, it will show the mix of fields through the chronological order.